# Node schedule not working with object variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scheduler

I have programmed a schedule in node:

```
function setTimer(time){
  t_SD1.on_h = time.on_h;
  t_SD1.on_m = time.on_m;
  t_SD1.off_h = time.off_h;
  t_SD1.off_m = time.off_m;
   console.log(t_SD1.on_h+' '+t_SD1.on_m);
}
var j = schedule.scheduleJob({hour: t_SD1.on_h, minute: t_SD1.on_m}, function(){
  console.log('ONNNN');
  console.log('0 '+t_SD1.on_m+' '+t_SD1.on_h+' * * *');
});
```

The time comes from:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(req.query.timer);


setTimer(obj);
```

Declaration:

```
var t_SD1 = {on_h: 14, on_m: 52, off_h: 14, off_m: 53};
```

Ok... now the problem:

When I start it without `setTimer()` it works fine. The schedule triggers at 14:52. But when I start the `setTimer()` function it does not work.

My console tells me the time `0 53 14 * * *`

I have also tried it with `parseInt(time.on_h)`, but the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand under which conditions it does and doesn't fail, but I think the problem stems from the fact that you call `scheduleJob()` before `setTimer()`. I think you need to adjust your first example to this:

```
function setTimer(time){
  t_SD1.on_h = time.on_h;
  t_SD1.on_m = time.on_m;
  t_SD1.off_h = time.off_h;
  t_SD1.off_m = time.off_m;
   console.log(t_SD1.on_h+' '+t_SD1.on_m);

  var j = schedule.scheduleJob({hour: t_SD1.on_h, minute: t_SD1.on_m}, function(){
    console.log('ONNNN');
    console.log('0 '+t_SD1.on_m+' '+t_SD1.on_h+' * * *');
  });
}
```

Comment: thx.. yes...:D just fixed it 10 minutes before your post.... hehe... i just needed a break:D very stupid issue^^